# android contentProvider notifyChange

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I am baffled by notifyChange machenism used in contentProvide:

```
// Tell the cursor what uri to watch, so it knows when its source data changes
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
```

and

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(noteUri, null);
```

Here are the questions (suppose the provider and the client are in different packages):

1. Is the contentResolver returned by Provider the same as Resolver returned by the client?
2. Is the cursor the same as returned by the provider and the client?
3. what is the Uri resolution to be notified changes? the entire table uri or a row?

Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. I am answering so that it is helpful for someone who comes across this question.

> 1. Is the contentResolver returned by Provider the same as Resolver returned by the client?

Yes, it is the same.

> 2. Is the cursor the same as returned by the provider and the client?

I suppose, you are asking this in the context of your first code snippet which is seen inside query() method. Here, you are setting the notification uri on the cursor which is to be returned to the client. So, obviously, the client and the provider are using the same cursor.

> 3. what is the Uri resolution to be notified changes? the entire table uri or a row?

Uri for notification depends on the operation:

1. insert() - The notification Uri is the table Uri appended with the
   id of the newly inserted row.
2. delete() and update() - Here, the Uri is the table Uri appended with the id of the deleted or updated row.